# Derby SELECT statement failing to find a specific string

Tags: sql, jdbc, derby

I have a table that contains a column called ATEST, in a schema called TESTSCHEMA, that is in a database called SESSION.

I am trying to find records whose ATEST column has a string called "MyTest".

I am using the following SQL:

```
  final String query = "SELECT * FROM SESSIONDATA.SESSIONS WHERE SESSION.TESTSCHEMA.ATEST = 'MyTest'";
```

Now I have placed several records whose ATEST column contains "MyTest". I use JDBC in the usual way:

```
     device = aConnect.prepareCall(query);

     ResultSet result = device.executeQuery();
```

Note that, for brevity, try and catch code is being omitted since I am not getting any exceptions thrown.

For some reason, I keep getting what amounts to empty result sets. I cannot get this statement to find any records despite the fact that I have several records in the database where ATEST = 'MyTest'!

Have I found a bug in Derby? Searches without WHERE clauses or where WHERE clauses look for numbers seem to work without problems. Why doesn't a WHERE clause that looks for a string find the strings, despite the fct that the strings are actually in the database???

Someone please advise.

Comment: You may want to try `atest LIKE '%MyTest%'` to see if there are maybe whitespace or the like in your values you don't see.

Comment: I tried your suggestio. Same result...

Comment: Then I have no idea. A bug like this is very unlikely, so it must be something in your setup. I would try on with LIKE (`like '%'`, then `like 'M%'`, `like '%t'`, ...) to narrow this down.

Comment: Execute your query in an ordinary JDBC query tool like SquirrelSQL or Derby's own "ij" tool. Then update your question to include **all** the details about your case. People are just guessing because you haven't provided any real details about what you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

Try sending like

```
  final String query = "SELECT * FROM SESSIONDATA.SESSIONS WHERE SESSION.TESTSCHEMA.ATEST = '''MyTest'''";
```

It should hit DB like

```
SELECT * FROM SESSIONDATA.SESSIONS WHERE SESSION.TESTSCHEMA.ATEST = 'MyTest'
```

instead of

```
SELECT * FROM SESSIONDATA.SESSIONS WHERE SESSION.TESTSCHEMA.ATEST =MyTest
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried following it and am getting the same result: the strinng isn't being found.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Derby. But your query looks strange:

- You say the database is called `SESSION`. So this is where you connect to. I wouldn't expect it's name in a query.
- Your schema is called `TESTSCHEMA`. So this is where the tables reside in. `ATEST` is a column. So aren't you missing the table name between schema and column in `TESTSCHEMA.ATEST`?
- You select from `SESSIONDATA.SESSIONS`. What is `SESSIONDATA` suddenly? It's neither of the names you mentioned. What is `SESSIONS`? Is that the table name?

I would expect a query about like this:

```
SELECT * FROM testschema.sessions WHERE atest = 'MyTest'
```

(Where the schema name might even be superfluous in case it's the default schema for your connection.)

Comment: Actually, that was my original SQL call. It doesn't find anything, either. That was why I tried what I tried...

Answer (score 0):

Try using a numeric value for referencing in place of 'Mytest'

Replace

SELECT * FROM SESSIONDATA.SESSIONS WHERE SESSION.TESTSCHEMA.ATEST = 'MyTest'

with

SELECT * FROM SESSIONDATA.SESSIONS WHERE SESSION.TESTSCHEMA.ATEST =  123